# How to show more than 5K records in views using addCustomView

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using MS CRM online & have a requirement to develop a custom view but during development I got stuck on one point. How can I show more than 5K records?

I am using addCustomView method for this & so will be using fetchxml query to get the records & as we all know per call fetchxml can fetch 5K records only (until we tweak it). Even I thought of adding few attributes as filter conditions to decrease the no of records but what I really want to know, is there any other way to achieve this?

Client's expectation: Need to use existing lookup view & should behave like OOTB lookup fields.

Please, let me know if you have any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, I believe there is a registry change you can make for onpremise but no such alternative for online.

However I don't think you really need it. Lookup controls implement paging, so you can see more than 5000 records by just using the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Let me check what you proposed.